# How to increase auto generated coupon codes limit in cart rule?

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

I have used auto generated option in cart rule for coupons but its limit to "11041 records found" How can I increase this limit in magento 2?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It was quite simple actually, thing is magento 2 have a limit of 11 to 10 thousand auto generated coupons but when I generate them again it work coupons were 20 thousand this time so I guess this is the way. Works for me.